# How to make checked and unchecked a checkbox using true and false value of json in angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a table whose data comes from loop in angular 7.Here every thing is working fine but as per my json, there is "enable":true and "enable":false in a column.Here if my value is true checkbox should be checked and if value is false checkbox should be unchecked in table.Here is my code below

### app.component.html

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
<td>{{user.id}}</td>
<td>{{user.name}}</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: any;

  constructor(private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

  users = [{"id":1,"name":"test","enable":true},{"id":2,"name":"test","enable":false}];


}
```

Comment: `[checked]="user.enabled"`

Comment: visit this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728198/uncheck-all-check-boxes-created-with-ngfor/51729657#51729657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" [checked]="user.enable"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```